# How do I display image count of specific type of image with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, if-statement

So I've got a page with 6 images. 4 are of some type of ball (basketball, baseball, etc.). One is of a truck, and another is random.

I have a from with two radio buttons which give the user the option to display the number of each type of image (Images of balls, images of trucks, etc). I need to write javascript/jquery to take the radio button they selected and then display the image count below in a span tag ("There are X amount of picture of a ball", "There are X amount of pictures of a truck"). I can figure out how to get values of what is checked but I have no idea how to get the image count of how many of each type of image. (Without just making seperate spans with the number preset and just displaing whichever count the user chooses)

Here is what I've got so far:

```
<div id="images">
<h3>Some Images</h3>
    <p><img src="firetruck.jpg" alt="pic of truck" >  |
    <img src="baseball.jpg" alt="pic of baseball" >  |
    <img src="soccer_ball.jpg" alt="pic of soccer ball" >
    </p>

    <p><img src="hockey_puck.jpg" alt="pic of hockey puck" >  |
    <img src="tennis_ball.jpg" alt="pic of tennis ball" >  |
    <img src="basketball.jpg" alt="pic of basketball" >     </p>

</div><!-- end of 'images' div -->


<input type="radio" name="imageCount" id="ballImages" value="ballImages">Images of Balls<br>
    <input type="radio" name="imageCount" id="truckImages" value="truckImages">Images of Trucks<br><br>
    <input type="button" name="btnImageCount" value="Image Count" onclick="getImageCount()">
    <span class="spanImageCount"></span>


<script>

function getImageCount()
{
    if ($("#ballImages").prop("checked"))
    {
    var count = $("#images img[src*="ball"]").length;
    document.write('<span class="spanImageCount">There are ' + count + ' images of a ball!</span>');
    }
    else if ($("#truckImages").prop("checked"))
    {
    var count = $("#images img[src*="truck"]").length;
    document.write('<span class="spanImageCount">There are ' + count + ' images of a truck!</span>');
    }
}
```

Comment: How, in your HTML, do you identify the image types?

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? Are you asking/open to a jQuery solution?

Comment: I hope you mean that the images are labelled or tagged in HTML in some way, right? How is the code going to know what's a ball, what's a truck, etc. (`data` attribute, or based on the filename, or something else?)

Comment: The image SRC contains either ball or truck in the image name so I would like to differentiate like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```js
// bind the click-handling anonymous function to the button-input:
$('input[name="btnImageCount"]').click(function(){
  // find the input element whose type is 'radio' and whose name is 'imageCount' which
  // is also checked:
  var chosen = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="imageCount"]:checked'),
      // if there is a chosen radio input, we get the 'type' of image we're looking for,
      // by removing the 'Images' string from the 'id', if there is no chosen radio input
      // we use a string of white-space:
      type = chosen ? chosen.id.replace('Images','') : ' ',
      // finding the images whose 'src' attribute contains the substring identified
      // above ('truck','ball' or ' ', the ' ' will deliberately not match):
      relevantImages = document.querySelectorAll('img[src*="' + type + '"]'),
      // if we have any relevant images, and the number (length) of those images
      // is greater than 0 we get the number of found images, otherwise we offer
      // a simple message to the user telling them to select a type of image:
      count = relevantImages && relevantImages.length > 0 ? 'There are ' + relevantImages.length + ' images of that type.' : 'Please select an image type.';
  // assigning the text of the 'span' to the count (or message) we set, above:
  $('span.spanImageCount').text(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">
  <h3>Some Images</h3>
  <p>
    <img src="firetruck.jpg" alt="pic of truck">|
    <img src="baseball.jpg" alt="pic of baseball">|
    <img src="soccer_ball.jpg" alt="pic of soccer ball">
  </p>

  <p>
    <img src="hockey_puck.jpg" alt="pic of hockey puck">|
    <img src="tennis_ball.jpg" alt="pic of tennis ball">|
    <img src="basketball.jpg" alt="pic of basketball">
  </p>

</div>
<!-- end of 'images' div -->


<label>
  <input type="radio" name="imageCount" id="ballImages" value="ballImages">Images of Balls
</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="imageCount" id="truckImages" value="truckImages">Images of Trucks
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="button" name="btnImageCount" value="Image Count" />
</label>
<span class="spanImageCount"></span>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:checked` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked).
  - [Substring-matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
  - [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: This worked!! Thanks so much! How can I get the message to say "There are" count "iamges of that type" instead of just the number? I can't seem to add a string inside the perenthesis

Comment: Just updated the answer to add that in; I also wrapped the `<input>` elements in `<label>` elements, in order that clicking the relevant text selects the relevant radio.

Comment: Works exactly the way I hoped. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your images have classes of either "ballImage" or "truckImage" you could do this:

```
function getImageCount(){
  if($("#ballImages").prop("checked")){
    var count = $(".ballImage").length;
    document.write('<span class="spanImageCount">There are ' + count + ' images of a ball!</span>');
  }
  else if($("#truckImages").prop("checked")){
    var count = $(".truckImage").length;
    document.write('<span class="spanImageCount">There are ' + count + ' images of a truck!</span>');
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why you were using document.write, but I would consider doing this:

Put a div in your html like this:

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

Then make your getImageCount function look like this:

```
function getImageCount(){
  if($("#ballImages").prop("checked")){
    var count = $(".ballImage").length;
    $("#message).html('<span class="spanImageCount">There are ' + count + ' images of a ball!</span>');
  }
  else if($("#truckImages").prop("checked")){
    var count = $(".truckImage").length;
    $("#message).html('<span class="spanImageCount">There are ' + count + ' images of a truck!</span>');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it to do what I want, but I cant get the response to show up on the current page. It shows the response of a new blank page.

Comment: Document.write() blanks the page.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work if the image src attribute contains "ball" or "truck" for every image.

```
var ballCount = 0;
$('img[src*=ball]').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
        ballCount+=1;
    }
});

var truckCount = 0;
$('img[src*=truck]').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
        truckCount+=1;
    }
});
```

instead, if image src doesn't contains that info, you need to give an id or a class to every image, to identify if that is a truck or a ball image. The above code change only at the line $('img[src*=something]') and became

with ids: `$('img[id^=truck]') //where ids need to be like truck1, truckTwo, truckSomething`

with classes: `$('.truck')`